# Unable to configure USB modem for 3G wifi dongle in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, modem, 3g

I have recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS. I wish to configure and use a Tata Photon Max Wifi Dongle as my internet connection. When I plug it into my brand new system, it does not get listed automatically although the lights on the device start blinking.

Can somebody please guide me on the steps to configure my usb modem?

PS: The usb modem works fine on my Windows 7 laptop.

Thanks

Comment: One additional information: My device is a Huawei EC315 model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself and got my internet connection to work. Not all the information available on the internet is organized. I will try to put forward the solution in a concise manner. I am using a Tata Photon Max Wifi dongle (EC315).

Steps:

1. Open a terminal window with root privileges and run the "lsusb" command.
2. Identify your device by the name of the manufacturer (Eg: Huawei) and note down the Vendor ID and Product ID details (Eg: 12d1:1f01).
3. Go to the /etc folder and check if there is a usb_modeswitch.conf file. If not, then usb_modeswitch needs to be installed first.
4. Go to the /usr/share/usb_modeswitch folder. Inside, there will be an archive file called configPack.tar.gz. Extract the contents of the file in a separate location and identify the config file corresponding to your device. For example, it may be named as 12d1:1f01 depending upon the output of your lsusb command.
5. Note the following values from that file: TargetVendor and MessageContent.
6. Edit the /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf file and append the following lines:

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1f01
TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x0031
MessageContent="5553424312345678000000000000061e000000000000000000000000000000

Please make sure that you put the right entry. DefaultVendor and DefaultProduct can be obtained from the lsusb command; TargetVendor and MessageContent from the file I mentioned above. TargetProduct will be 0x0031. 0x0031 represents a modem.
Save it and close the file.

7. Open a new terminal window and run the following command:

sudo usb_modeswitch ‐c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf

This will activate your internet connection and a notification message will be displayed after a couple of seconds. The connection will be marked as a wired connection.

Please note that the changes in the usb_modeswitch.conf file need to be performed only once. However, the "sudo usb_modeswitch ‐c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf" command may need to be run every time the computer is restarted. One may bypass this requirement by updating the ".profile" file under your home folder so that this command is executed automatically every time at logon.

I hope this will resolve the issue and the internet connection should be good to go.